# 'str' object has no attribute 'sort'

Tags: python

I am quite new to python and was wondering if someone could help me fix a problem. Im making an anagram checker and have run into an issue.

```
def anagram():
    worda = input("Please choose your first word:")     
    wordb = input("Please choose your second word:")
    if worda.isalpha():
        print((worda),"is a word")
    else:
        print((worda),"is not a word, please try again")      
        anagram()
    if wordb.isalpha():
        print((wordb),"is a word")         
    else:
        print((wordb),"is not a word,please try again")
        anagram()
    worda.sort
    wordb.sort    

anagram()
```

I get the error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'sort'when I try to run it.

Comment: Error seems pretty self-explanatory. You have a str not a list.

Comment: Well, yes. Not only does `str` not have `sort`, if it *did* you're missing the parentheses needed to actually *call* it.

Comment: Please describe what output you want your code to produce? What is the thought process behind sorting a string? What is it that you want your algorithm to do?

Comment: what you are looking for is `sorted()`

Comment: even if you use what has been suggested in the answers, your code still makes little sense. You do nothing after so not sure what it is going to achieve even if it worked.

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham After I found the answer to my problem I was going to print to the user if the words were anagrams or not and I had not written that code yet.

Comment: @mrdomoboto The purpose of sorting the string was to then see if worda was equal to wordb which would make it an anagram but I didnt know how to do that.

Comment: @SlicedBread Okay, that is solid reasoning, and comparing `==` two sorted strings is one way to check for an anagram. For other problems I would begin by recognizing the data structures that you need to work with, in this case `str`. You can then search the python standard library to see if there are methods that can help you with achieving a certain solution.

Comment: @mrdomoboto Ok, I am planning on learning a lot more about python in the future. Here is the last part of the code for anyone interested     worda = "".join(sorted(worda))
    wordb = "".join(sorted(wordb))
    if worda == wordb:
        print ("This is an anagram")
    else:
        print("This is not an anagram")

Comment: @SlicedBread note that you can compare lists for equality, you don't actually need to reassemble the string in this case

Comment: @Sliced Bread, you don't need to sort strings to see if they are anagrams, you can see if the letter count is the same `collections.Counter(worda ) == collections.Counter(wordb)`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Of course there are more efficient solutions, and `Counter` yields a O(n) efficiency, but I wanted him to be able to explain the reasoning behind sorting. More so than which particular approach to use. You could implement your own function to emulate `Counter` too. It's why I prefaced by saying -> "two sorted strings is *one* way to check for an anagram."

Comment: @mrdomoboto, I actually meant to ping the OP. I edited the comment

Comment: Thank you so much for your help guys, I had looked for ages to try and fix the problem and I've gained a lot more knowledge about python.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

strings in Python are immutable, so it would make no sense for them to have a `sort` method, what you can do is use `sorted(worda)`, which returns a sorted list made out of the characters of the string.

Then to get a string back again, you can use `''.join(sorted(worda))`

Answer (score 1):

In Python, it is not possible to sort strings in lexicographic order, since strings are immutable. Instead, you must use the `sorted` function, which takes the string, converts it to a list, and then sorts that. Once you have done that, you can use the `join` function to convert your result back into a string.

```
worda = "".join(sorted(worda))
```

Comment: No need to call `list`: a string is iterable.

Answer (score 0):

There is no property as `sort` or any `sort()` function with `str` in Python. For sorting the `str` you can use [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) as:

```
>>> x = 'abcsd123ab'
>>> sorted(x) # returns list
['1', '2', '3', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'd', 's']
```

If you need the result as sorted `string`, you need to explicitly [`join`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_join.htm) it as:

```
>>> ''.join(sorted(x))
'123aabbcds'
```

Comment: @mrdomoboto The purpose of sorting the string was to then see if worda was equal to wordb which would make it an anagram but I didnt know how to do that. -Padraic Cunningham After I found the answer to my problem I was going to print to the user if the words were anagrams or not and I had not written that code yet.